# Using regular expressions, extracting data

Tags: regex, perl, shell

Hi I am using shell command line and trying to extract course first two column and the grade column from a file.

I am using

```
 cat data.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 1,2
```

By this code I am also getting (001234), Student Id and some other subscripts in my output which I don't need . How can I only get 3-4 letter words from these column as that's what I believe should be done.
Heres the input file

```
                                          ATT    ERN  CrGPA    Qpts
                                          ---    ---  -----    ----
    *     Student Id -
                (001234) UNIV OF SOME COOL PLACE
           BIOL 310  GENERAL BIOLOGY  BIOS 101 W       3.00    0.00                   0.00    0.00  20081
           CIBI 300  FUND OF BIOL I   BIOS 110 B       3.00   3.00   3.00    9.00  20072
           CIBI 300  FUND OF BIOL II  BIOS 120 D       3.00   3.00   3.00    3.00  20082
           CIBI 300  FUND OF BIOL II  BIOS 120 W       3.00   0.00   0.00    0.00  20102
           QUIM 300  GEN CHEMISTRY I  CHEM 121 F       3.00   0.00   3.00    0.00  20091
           QUIM 300  GEN CHEMISTRY I CHEM 121L F       1.00   0.00   1.00    0.00  20091
           CSC 303  FUNDMTL STRUCTU   CSC100+ F       3.00   0.00   3.00    0.00  20091
```

result should be

```
  BIOL 310     W
  CIBI 300     B
  CIBI 300     D
  CIBI 300     W 
  So on..
```

Note CSC in column 1 is 3 letter

Comment: how does the input file look?

Comment: @maria This information should go into the question, not into a comment. Just [edit] the question.

Comment: ok sorry about that

Comment: And the problem is... ?

Comment: Please add expected output.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your input data is composed of **fixed-width columns**, which means you need to base your solution on **column (character) positions** rather than fields delineated by separators:

```
$ tail +5 data.txt | cut -c 12-15,16-20,47-48

BIOL 310  W
CIBI 300  B
CIBI 300  D
CIBI 300  W
QUIM 300  F
QUIM 300  F
CCOM 303  F
```

- `tail +5` skips the header lines
- `cut -c 12-15,16-20,47-48` specifies the strings to extract as a list of column-position ranges; in the case of the 2nd and 3rd output fields, this includes the space character preceding the field.

---

Original answer, before the requirements were clarified:

In case you simply want to ignore the header lines, a simple fix would be:

```
awk 'NF >= 11 { print $1, $2 }' data.txt
```

It looks like all data rows have (at least) 11 fields, so `NF >= 11` ensures that only data rows are processed, and `print $1, $2` simply prints the first 2 whitespace-separated fields, separated by `awk`'s default output separator (`OFS`), which is a space.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR>4{print $1,$2"\t",$(NF-5)}' file

BIOL 310     W
CIBI 300     B
CIBI 300     D
CIBI 300     W
QUIM 300     F
QUIM 300     F
CCOM 303     F
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Can you also tell how can I negate W and F from  the 5th colummn

Comment: I just want to display ABCD not W F

Comment: If you mean the column placed under E in PLACE I can't see any A or C.

Comment: Theres a B and D. If you can help that will be great

Comment: awk 'NR>4{print $1,$2"\t",$(NF-5)}' file | awk '$3!~/W|F/'
CIBI 300  B
CIBI 300  D Not much but this is all I can produce.